# How do I print a timestamp with LLDB in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, profiling, timestamp, lldb

I am trying to profile some code, and I need to see the timestamps of when certain commands are run. I could do this by inserting `NSLog()` statements in my code, but I'd prefer to use the debugger for a number of reasons.

I've setup a breakpoint on each significant event, and I can the breakpoints to print out a message using a "Log Message" action, but I'd like it to print out an `NSLog()` style timestamp (with millisecond accuracy).

Is there an LLDB command to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This technique works, but seems a bit hacky (surely there's a better way?):

Call `NSLog()` from a Debugger Command:

```
call (void) NSLog(@"An Important Event Occurred")
```

Comment: Yes, adding a command on the breakpoints to call NSLog() is definitely one solution - this will execute NSLog() in your application.  Another option is to add python scripting on the breakpoints, get the current time in python and print it - this should be faster than doing an inferior function call (inferior function call means executing a function call in your app, instead of in Xcode/lldb).  I don't think the Xcode breakpoint editor can add python commands, though, you'll need to do it in the debugger console window or via a `~/.lldbinit` file (or a command file you source in the console).

Comment: That's disappointing, I thought this would be a relatively common (and easily implemented) feature in a debugger, and I guess one more casualty in the GDB to LLDB transition. :-(

Comment: I don't think you're seeing an lldb vrs. gdb change, maybe an Xcode 3 vrs Xcode 4 change?

Comment: You're right, the timestamp feature in gdb doesn't do what I thought it would by its description. That said, shouldn't this really be a built-in feature of either LLDB or Xcode's debugger-wrapper-GUI?

Comment: It's a good feature idea, I'd recommend filing a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ suggesting it.

Answer (score 1):

In the message line write: 
[YOUR MESSAGE] @Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000@
That will give you a print of the timestamp in miliseconds

Comment: it works!  it's  the best solution for me, then I can filter out all debug message with the button in the left-bottom of the console.